# Node does not render static files when integrating React app. Why is this happening, what should be done to fix this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Im a total beginer in React and Webpack, Node and all the stuff. Im targeting to create some pretty simple fullstack app with React + Redux + Falcor + Node. There is a book by K.Przeorski( actualy its a tutorial building this app, and so Im mfollowing it). The hardest, as for me, is Webpack conf part. There is an example there where webpack 1.1 is used. But I try to manage it with Webpack 4. my webpack.config.js looks like this

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app.js')],
  module: {
    rules: [
         {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['babel-loader']
         }
   ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'app.js'
 },
 devServer: {
   inline: true,
   port: 3000,
   contentBase: './dist'
 }
```

};

And here are "sripts" from package.json

```
 "scripts": {
   "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
   "start:dev": "webpack --mode development && node server",
   "webpack": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
   "build": "webpack --mode production",
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 }
```

No errors occure when i run my app, bundle file app.js is built and in right dist folder. But On React is present in my browser while the Node server is on and listening. The ook Im reading gives somth like this

```
"start": "npm run webpack; node server"
```

but this happens to be invalid in Webpack4, as far as I understood tutorials and docs for webpack4 - in simple cases, like mine, there is no need in configuration, the defaults should be ok. Is there a serious difference between this

```
webpack --mode development && node server
```

and this?

```
webpack --mode development ; node server
```

The latest shows a syntax error.

When the server starts and react app appears in browser there should be  a request from the app through falcors API to fetch some data from the server. I  my case no request is made? actually no react in my browser. hre is a chunk of my server.js

```
  const model = new falcor.Model({ cache: cache });

  app.use('/model.json', falcorExpress.dataSourceRoute( (req, res) => { 
    console.log("REQESTING MODEL");
    return model.asDataSource() 
  } ));

  //app.use(express.static('../dist/app.js')); //<= these were my tryouts :(
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

    // app.get('*', function response(req, res) {<= these were my tryouts :(
    //   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
   // });

   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     Article.find( (err, articlesDocs) => {

     const ourArticles = articlesDocs.map((articleItem) => {
       return `<h2>${articleItem.articleTitle}</h2>
          ${articleItem.articleContent}`;}).join('<br/>');

     res.send(`<h1>Publishing App Initial
            Application!</h1> ${ourArticles}`);    
   });
});
```

I do have nobody alive to help with this around me, so please help me to get through this and understand how it should work. Would greatly appriciate any help. Sorry for such a long story .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this script in your package.json?

```
watch": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot"
```

npm run watch

You start your local dev server, then in a separate terminal you start your webpack dev server. Then they can talk to each other through the appropriate localhost:xxxx

Here is my webpack config for an example project 
https://github.com/arn1313/kritter-frontend/blob/master/webpack.config.js